# Como filtrar correctamente en rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails

tengo un filtro en mi vista de reportes, donde puedo seleccionar un servicio.

en mi controlador lo tengo de esta manera.

```
    if !params[:service_request][:benefit_id].blank?
        @service_requests = @service_requests.joins(:service).where(service: {benefit_id: params[:service_request][:benefit_id]})
    end
```

de esta manera se esta llenando la data

```
        beneficios = Benefit.where(id: service_requests_all.joins(:service).select(:benefit_id))
        beneficios.each do |benefit|
            indicador_general = []
            indicador_general[0] = "Solicitudes de " + benefit.nombre
            total = @service_requests.joins(:service).where(service: {benefit_id: benefit.id})
            if total
                indicador_general[1] = total.size
                total_con_cita = total.joins(:appointment).where(appointment: {status: ["Por Asistir","Asistio","Vencida"]})
                if total_con_cita.size>0
                    arreglo_citas = []
                    con_cita_por_asistir = total.joins(:appointment).where(appointment: {status: ["Por Asistir"]})
                    con_cita_asistio = total.joins(:appointment).where(appointment: {status: ["Asistio"]})
                    con_cita_vencida = total.joins(:appointment).where(appointment: {status: ["Vencida"]})
                    indicador = []
                    indicador[0] = "Con Citas"
                    indicador[1] = total_con_cita.size
                    arreglo_citas << indicador
                    indicador = []
                    indicador[0] = "Con Citas Asistidas"
                    indicador[1] = con_cita_asistio.size
                    arreglo_citas << indicador
                    indicador = []
                    indicador[0] = "Con Citas Por Asistir"
                    indicador[1] = con_cita_por_asistir.size
                    arreglo_citas << indicador
                    indicador = []
                    indicador[0] = "Con Citas Vencidas"
                    indicador[1] = con_cita_vencida.size
                    arreglo_citas << indicador
                    indicador_general[2] = arreglo_citas
                else
                    indicador_general[2] = []
                end
```

Asi tengo mi filtro en las vista

```
= f.collection_select :benefit_id, @benefit, :id, :nombre, {prompt:true}, {:class => "form-select"}
```

tengo entendido que si pasamos una condicion en la vista por ejemplo

```
if params[:service_request][:benefit_id].blank?
```

deberia mostrarnos como lo tenemos en un principio y luego caer en el else para mostrar el deseado pero no logro hacer que me retorne un valor unico de ese arreglo de indicadores

de esta manera estoy recorriendo ese arreglo

```
- @indicadores[1..@indicadores.size].each_with_index do |indicador, i|
```